# How to convert Dictionary<string, object> to Dictionary<string, string> in c#

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I have below code in C#

```
Dictionary<string, object> dObject = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

I want to convert `dObject` to `Dictionary<string, string>`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Use the ToDictionary method:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dString = dObject.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value.ToString());
```

Here you reuse the key from the original dictionary and you convert the values to strings using the ToString method.

If your dictionary can contain null values you should add a null check before performing the ToString:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dString = dObject.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value == null ? "" : k.Value.ToString());
```

The reason this works is that the `Dictionary<string, object>` is actually an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>>`. The above code example iterates through the enumerable and builds a new dictionary using the ToDictionary method.

**Edit:**

In .Net 2.0 you cannot use the ToDictionary method, but you can achieve the same using a good old-fashioned foreach:

```
Dictionary<string, string> sd = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in dict)
{
  sd.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value.ToString());
}
```

**Edit2:**

If you are on .Net 2.0 and you can have null values in the dictionary the following should be safe:

```
Dictionary<string, string> sd = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in dict)
{
  sd.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value == null ? "" : keyValuePair.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I am using .NET 2.0, is possible in it. I am not getting "ToDictionary"

Comment: @Rune: Will `k.Value.ToString()` return always the same as `(string)k.Value`?

Comment: @Oscar: No. the (string)k.Value will fail if the value is a non-string object. The ToString() is safe for all non-null values.

Comment: @Rune: Yes, I know that. Let's suppose all elements are strings. Will `ToString()` and `(string)` return the same?

Comment: What if there is NULL values in the key in .NET 2.0 solution

Comment: @Oscar: Yes. If all values are strings then they will do the same. In that case I believe casting to a string will be slightly faster.

Comment: @MKS: Good point. You would have to do the same null check here as in the Linq-version.

Comment: Might I suggest using `Convert.ToString()` instead.  So it will be a little easier to deal with `null` values.  `Convert.ToString(keyValuePair.Value)` or `Convert.ToString(keyValuePair.Value) ?? String.Empty`

Comment: @Jeff M: Yeah. Good point! Convert.ToString is nice since you don't have to do a null check then. Convert.ToString(keyValuePair.Value) will be enough since it returns an empty string for null values.

Comment: @Rune: Actually it will return `null` in the case the argument is `null`.  Which is why I did the coalescing there.  ;)

Comment: @Jeff: `Convert.ToString()` actually returns `String.Empty` when the provided `value` is `null`.

Comment: @Jaroslav: Ah, I stand corrected.  I was testing with the wrong overload.  `Convert.ToString(string)` returns `null`.

Comment: @Jeff. Yep, that one actually does nothing else than returning the provided `value`.

Answer (score 9):

.NET 3.5:

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = dObject.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => Convert.ToString(kvp.Value));
```

.NET 2.0:

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in dObject) result.Add(kvp.Key, Convert.ToString(kvp.Value));
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using .net 2.0:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dString = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> item in dObject)
{
    dString.Add(item.Key, item.Value.ToString());
    //here item.Value.ToString() is an example
    //you should convert your item to string according to the requirement
}
```

Comment: What if there is NULL values in it?

Comment: @MKS: That's why I'm saying "convert your item to string according to the requirement", for example you can use `string.Empty` for null values, or the string "NULL" for null values...everything depends on the requirement.

Comment: Sometime there can be null values also in the key, please suggest how to convert it?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Dictionary<string, string> newDictionary = dObject.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => (string) k.Value);
```

Comment: This will fail if the dictionary contains non-string values. You cannot convert an int to a string for instance.

Comment: First of all I am using .NET 2.0, is possible in it. I am not getting "ToDictionary" method.

Comment: Well, I suppose if he wants to do it is because the dictionary contains `strings`, but anyway, that's valid.

Comment: Yeah true.. But ToString does not always produce a nice string. It all depends on your Dictionary objects anyhow. :)

Comment: Since you are using .NET 2.0, foreach will be your bestest buddy! GL

Answer (score 1):

In .Net 2.0 probably your best friend is **foreach** loop:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dObject = new Dictionary<string, object>();
Dictionary<string, string> newObjects = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValuePair in dObject)
{
    newObjects.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<string, string> dString = dObject.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.ToString());
```

It's just idea. You can insert any verifications.