# Dictionary<string, object> to Dictionary<string, float>

Tags: c#, linq

I'm currently working on a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application. Given is a `Dictionary<string, object>`. I need to write a method to transform the structure to a `Dictionary<string, float>`.

```
private List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>> CreateResult(List<Dictionary<string, object>> items)
{
    var result = new List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
       var item = items[i].ToDictionary<string, float>(v => v); // Error, wrong approach
       result.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>(i, new Dictionary<string, float>(item)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Unfortunately my method does not work, neither I don't really know if it's the right approach to transform all values of my dictionary to type float.

Do you know a good/save way to transform all values in my Dicitonary from type object to type float?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `Unfortunately my method does not work`. Why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942624/how-to-convert-dictionarystring-object-to-dictionarystring-string-in-c-sha

Comment: Why is your return type of the method not `List<Dictionary<string, float>>`?

Comment: @accordo777 you can write a simple LINQ query to return what you want. Why the KeyValuePair? Do you really need it?

Comment: `var result = items.Select(d=>d.ToDictionary(k=>k.Key, k=> Convert.ToSingle(k.Value))).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
private List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>> CreateResult(List<Dictionary<string, object>> items)
    {
        var result = new List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            var currentDic = new Dictionary<string, float>();
            var item = items[i];
            foreach (var itm in item)
            {
                currentDic.Add(itm.Key, (float)itm.Value);
            }

            result.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>(i, currentDic));
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You've changed the return type, without knowing why OP has used the original return type.

Comment: he said I'm currently working on a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application. Given is a Dictionary<string, object>. I need to write a method to transform the structure to a Dictionary<string, float>...

Comment: @NaDeRStar you've changed the result. The OP's code retutns the *index* of each Dictionary as well

Comment: Right with you guys, answer just updated

Comment: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the dictionaries and insert the index with a single (ugly) LINQ statement :

```
var result=items.Select((dct,i)=>new KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>(
                                           i,
                                           dct.ToDictionary(p=>p.Key,p=>(float)p.Value))
                       ).ToList();
```

A `KeyValuePair` doesn't offer any advantages except the property names. You could simplify the query by using value tuples:

```
var result=items.Select((dct,i)=>(i,dct.ToDictionary(p=>p.Key,p=>(float)p.Value)))
                 .ToList();
```

And name the tuple items in the return type :

```
private List<(int index , Dictionary<string, float> dict)> CreateResult(List<Dictionary<string, object>> items)
{
    var result=items.Select((dct,i)=>(i,dct.ToDictionary(p=>p.Key,p=>(float)p.Value)))
                    .ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you *know* that the dictionary with `object` values contains only `float` values, you can do a typecast in `ToDictionary`:

```
private List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>> CreateResult(List<Dictionary<string, object>> items)
{
    var result = new List<KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
    {
       var item = items[i].ToDictionary<string, float>(v => v.Key, v = (float)v.Value);
       result.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<string, float>>(i, item));
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can replace the typecast with any conversion that you deem necessary. The important thing is that the return type of the second lambda expression in `ToDictionary` is `float`.